# Trouble incorporating getter into a static method

Tags: java, static, accessor, mutators

My first goal was too write a class that represents a book, and write a getFinishedPercent method. I believe this is all correct.

My second goal is to write a class with a static method named compareBooks that receives two book objects as parameters, and prints the title of the book that has been read the most of (by percent). And if both percents are the same it will print. "Wow, a tie!".

I've written the class Book that has my fields, getters, and mutators but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my compareBooks class...

### Book Class

```
 public class Book {

private String title; 
private String author; 
private int pages; 
private int lastPageRead; 

public Book(String title, String author, int pages, int 
 lastPageRead) {
    this.title = title; 
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.lastPageRead = lastPageRead;

}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public int getPages() {
    return pages;
}
public int lastPageRead() {
    return lastPageRead;
}
public double getFinishedPercent() {
    double percent = 0;
    percent = lastPageRead / pages;
    return percent;
}
 }
```

### compareBooks class

```
 public class compareBooks {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Book book1 = new Book("Building Java Programs", "Stuart 
 Reges & Marty Stepp", 1194, 586);
    Book book2 = new Book("Java is hard","Brian May", 1334,  
 23);   

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void compare(Book book1, Book book2){
    if(book1.getFinishedPercent() == book2.getFinishedPercent()){
        System.out.println("Wow, a tie!");
    }else{
      //other logic
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Book book1 = new Book("Building Java Programs", "Stuart 
 Reges & Marty Stepp", 1194, 586);
    Book book2 = new Book("Java is hard","Brian May", 1334,  
 23);   
     compare(book1, book2);
 }
```

You can do this. If your method is static (or not) does not matter in this case.

Comment: I attempted what you wrote but I end up with the tie statement every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class compareBooks {

public static class Book {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private double pages;
    private double lastPageRead;

    Book(String title, String author, int pages, int
            lastPageRead) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.lastPageRead = lastPageRead;

    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public double getPages() {
        return pages;
    }
    public double lastPageRead() {
        return lastPageRead;
    }
    public double getFinishedPercent() {

        return lastPageRead / pages;

    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Book book1 = new Book("Building Java Programs", "Stuart Reges & Marty Stepp",
            1194, 586);

    Book book2 = new Book("Java is hard","Brian May", 1334,
            23);


    System.out.println(book1.getFinishedPercent());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still accessing this problem, Victor's solution looks good and I think OP was very close to a correct solution. The reason OP was getting the same result each time is because getFinishedPercent() is dividing a smaller integer by a larger integer, and since we're dealing only with ints, the result is truncated to 0 each time, which is then saved as a double after the fact. An easy fix without casting or even declaring an additional variable would be to replace:

```
public double getFinishedPercent() {
    double percent = 0;
    percent = lastPageRead / pages;
    return percent;
}
```

...with...

```
public double getFinishedPercent() {
    return (lastPageRead*1.0) / pages;
}
```

For anyone who Googled this homework problem and is new to this topic of integer division, here's a quick review page about basic mathematics in Java: https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm